# solr sort slow when using sorting by alphaOnlySort

Tags: sorting, search, solr, lucene

so I have this in my solr schema

```
<field name="sort_alpha" type="alphaOnlySort" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
```

now whenever i do sorts including this field eg...

```
/solr/collection1/select?fl=*&..etc..etc..&sort=sort_alpha+asc
```

This ends up being really really slow

but then when i remove the sort parameter

```
/solr/collection1/select?fl=*&..etc..etc..&sort=sort_alpha+asc
```

It becomes much faster...

How can I make solr execute a sorted query without incurring the speed punishments

### Additional Information

Here's the definition of the alphaOnlySort field

```
  <!-- This is an example of using the KeywordTokenizer along
         With various TokenFilterFactories to produce a sortable field
         that does not include some properties of the source text
      -->
    <fieldType name="alphaOnlySort" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
      <analyzer>
        <!-- KeywordTokenizer does no actual tokenizing, so the entire
             input string is preserved as a single token
          -->
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <!-- The LowerCase TokenFilter does what you expect, which can be
             when you want your sorting to be case insensitive
          -->
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <!-- The TrimFilter removes any leading or trailing whitespace -->
        <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />
        <!-- The PatternReplaceFilter gives you the flexibility to use
             Java Regular expression to replace any sequence of characters
             matching a pattern with an arbitrary replacement string,
             which may include back references to portions of the original
             string matched by the pattern.

             See the Java Regular Expression documentation for more
             information on pattern and replacement string syntax.

             http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.6.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/package-summary.html
          -->
        <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory"
                pattern="([^a-z])" replacement="" replace="all"
        />
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

Comment: How is the fieldType that belongs to that alphaOnlySort? Is it tokenized?

Comment: Please also let us know how many documents do you have

Comment: @cheffe checkout my additional information......@Paweł Róg i have millions of documents (around 100,000,000)

Comment: Can you specify how slow is "slow" and how fast is "faster"? You say "but then when i remove the sort parameter

/solr/collection1/select?fl=*&..etc..etc..&sort=sort_alpha+asc
It becomes much faster..." but your query still shows the same sort